# Array of struct C language

Tags: c, struct

In my program, I have to create structs, in my case,  I have struct Processor here is my example:

```
struct Processor{
    int id;
    struct Task **task;
}
```

In the main I create set of processors (2 processors for example), and I have to add in tasks in each processor using this function 
`struct Processor * create_processor(int id,  struct Task **task );`

Here is the function:

```
struct Processor * create_processor(int id, struct Task **task){
    struct Processor * pr = (struct Processor *) (malloc(sizeof(struct Processor)));
    pr->id = id;
    //how to initialize Task set??
    return pr;
}
```

Now how to initialize the set of tasks in the function? and how to use elements of taskset?  I used `processor[1]->task[1]->id = 5;` but it returns ERROR `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Help please

Comment: Have you tried the (pretty obvious) `pr->task = task;`?

Comment: Also note that you only allocate memory for ***one*** `Processor` structure. And remember that array indexes are *zero* based.

Comment: thanks, yes i tried that but the same problm, it show : `request for member ‘task’ in something not a structure or union`

Comment: For each processor i allocate memory using `pr[1]=create_processor(1, NULL);` but i don't know if it is correcte i mean NULL

Comment: Please provide structure of Task

Comment: here is : `struct Task{ int id; int WCET;}`

Comment: help  it's urgent please

Comment: @ikram Maybe to you it's urgent but you're asking complete strangers for free help.

Comment: Your error is probably in the code you haven't shown us.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that others can compile and run that reproduces your problem.

Comment: If you want better help, improve the question. I can't see any reason why @Someprogrammerdude 's suggestion wouldn't work, so it's time for you to post the [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that gives that error.

Comment: See also many similar questions, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761809/nested-struct-variable-initialization

Comment: Thanks every one ..That's OK i will rewrite my question Now.... but to resume  i want just to know how to access the elements of a struct table (array struct) that is part of another array struct. and i will try it and show you the result.

Comment: And please take some time to read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
struct Processor * pr = (struct Processor *) (malloc(sizeof(struct Processor)));
```

you've now initialized an empty `Processor` struct.  Since the `task` member of the struct is a pointer (actually a double-pointer) all you have in your freshly initialized `Processor` is equivalent to: `struct Processor { id: 0, task: 0 }`, i.e. it just contains a null pointer for the `task` member.  That's probably why you get `Segmentation fault`, which is the type of error that occurs when your program accesses uninitialized memory.

You'll also have to malloc an array of `Task*` (task pointers) for however many tasks each processor has to have.  E.g.

```
pr.task = (struct Task **) malloc(sizeof(struct Task *) * N_TASKS);  // pr.task should probably be called pr.tasks??
```

then you also need to initialize memory for each actual task:

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < N_TASKS; idx++) {
    pr.task[idx] = (struct Task *) malloc(sizeof(struct Task));
}
```

and so on for each `Processor` you want to initialize.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help. I suppose you allocate memory for tasks before calling your function. Here you have 10 tasks and I create one processor with 3 tasks:

```
struct Processor{
    int id;
    struct Task **task;
};

struct Task{ int id; int WCET;};

struct Processor * create_processor(int id, struct Task **task){
    struct Processor * pr = (struct Processor *) (malloc(sizeof(struct Processor)));
    pr->id = id;
    pr->task = task;
    return pr;
}


int main() {
    struct Task taskArray[10]; /* memory for 10 tasks */
    struct Task * taskPtrArray[3]; /* pointers to 3 tasks */
    taskPtrArray[0] = &taskArray[2]; /* pointer to task 2 */
    taskPtrArray[1] = &taskArray[6]; /* pointer to task 6 */
    taskPtrArray[2] = &taskArray[9]; /* pointer to task 9 */

    struct Processor * p1 = create_processor(1, taskPtrArray);

    printf("p1->id = %d \n", p1->id);
    p1->task[2]->WCET = 999;
    printf("p1->task[2]->WCET = %d \n", taskArray[9].WCET);
}
```

The output is:

p1->id = 1

p1->task[2]->WCET = 999

---

As "Some programmer dude" said. The function assing tasks with:

```
pr->task = task;
```